# Setting many to many relationship in laravel with stock attribute

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on an e-commerce web where you can buy some items, say shirts... I have three models Item, ItemColor and ItemSize. I have set up a many to many relationship where an item in the shop can have many colors and many sizes available but each of these items will have a stock on its own, here is where things get complicated for me.

If I create an item, for example a shirt X, I can attach to that shirt different colors and sizes available (many to many), a shirt with black color and size M will have three in stock, but how can I set up so each type of shirt has a stock?? I'm failing to see this in a clear way...

Where should I put stock attribute? in pivot table maybe?

Here are my models and migrations:

```
//item model
protected $table = 'items';


    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ItemColor');
    }

    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ItemSize');
    }

//tiemsize model

protected $table = 'item_sizes';


    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Item');
    }

//item colors

protected $table = 'item_colors';


    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Item');
    }
```

And migrations

```
//pivot table
Schema::create('item_size_color', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('item_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items');
            $table->unsignedInteger('item_size_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('item_size_id')->references('id')->on('item_sizes');
            $table->unsignedInteger('item_color_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('item_color_id')->references('id')->on('item_sizes');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

//items table
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

//items color table
Schema::create('item_colors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

//items size table
Schema::create('item_sizes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Mock up controller method, how can I set stock?

```
public function create(Create $request)
    {
        $item = new Item();
        $item->colors->attach($request->input('availableColors'));
        $item->sizes->attach($request->input('availableSizes'));
        $item->sizes = $request->input('color');
        $title = $request('title');
        if($request->hasFile('image')){ $item->image = $this->uploadFile($request, 'image'); }
        $item->save();

        $item->load('sizes');
        $item->load('colors');


        return response()->json([
            'item' => $item,
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: The relations shouldn't be manytomany but Manytoone. 1 item is a shirt with color, size and stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think belongsToMany doesn't fit for you, and you should add independent entity ItemOption and work with it in controller, view, requests.

**Models:**

```
class ItemOption extens Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['item_id', 'item_color_id', 'item_size_id', 'stock'];

    public function color()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ItemColor::class);
    }

    public function size()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ItemSize::class);
    }
}

class Item extens Model
{
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemOption::class);
    }

    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ItemSize::class, ItemOption::class);
    }

    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ItemColor::class, ItemOption::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function create(Create $request)
{
    $item = new Item();
    $item->title = $request->input('title');;

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $item->image = $this->uploadFile($request, 'image');
    }

    $item->save();

    foreach($request->input('options') as $option){
        $option = $item->options()->firstOrNew([
            'item_size_id' = $option['size_id'],
            'item_color_id' = $option['color_id']
        ]);

        $option->stock = $option['stock'];
        $option->save();
    }

    $item->load('options');
    $item->load('sizes');
    $item->load('colors');

    //or $item->load(['options.size', 'options.color']);

    return response()->json([
        'item' => $item,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, what relations would ItemColor/Size model have?

Comment: Looks like you don't need relations in these models.